# how to use Enter on softkeyboard for my app?

Tags: android, keyevent, enter

I have big problem with my keyevent i am trying to call my another acvitity but the keyevent is not working please check what mistake i made for my code. actually i created one carousel design if i press softkeyboard enter button in my laptop the keyevent is not working...

This case is not working for me...

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                System.out.println("enter pressed");
            if(position==0);{
                Intent intent = new Intent(sampleActivity.this, test.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

[image]
                }

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Did you noticed the semicolon behind the if statement? `if(position==0);` make the if-clause quite useless and the following code will always be executed. As I'm not sure what error your experiencing I also don#t know if this will solve your troubles :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to enable your keyboard input. Even though the developer documentation says keyboard support is enabled by default it doesn't seem to be that way in SDK rev 20. I explicitly enabled keyboard support in my emulator's config.ini file and that worked!

Add: hw.keyboard=yes

To: ~/.android/avd/.avd/config.ini

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#hardwareopts

Comment: please see my screen shot first i am asking if press enter button in my keyboard the particular selected activity will open each item..I am using onitemclickListener its working fine but the keyEvent.keycode_enter is not working why if you know please tell me clearly....

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct (apart from the synthax error), the only difference I see from working examples is your event.getAction() condition. I'd suggest to check the ACTION_DOWN clause.